# How can I troubleshoot a CIFS mount that breaks after 15 minutes?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, samba, cifs

#### Context

I mount two Samba shares in a large corporate network (e.g. share A and B) on a machine with Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Both mounts start out fine, but share B stops working after some time. This is what I see when I do `ls -lah` in the `~/mnt` folder when `share_B` has stopped working:

```
ls: cannot access 'share_B': No such file or directory
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4.0K Sep 13 19:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 user user 4.0K Oct  6 18:09 ..
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? share_B
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user    0 May 15 23:17 share_A
```

Both shares use the same credentials, and the same options ins `/etc/fstab`:

```
//company.network.com/share_A /home/user/mnt/share_A cifs uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=3.1.1,noserverino,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8
//company.network.com/share_B /home/user/mnt/share_B cifs uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=3.1.1,noserverino,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8
```

When I do `sudo mount -t cifs` to inspect all options used for the mounts I see this (regardless of before or after `share_B` has stopped working):

```
//company.network.com/share_A /home/user/mnt/share_A type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=user,uid=1001,forceuid,gid=1001,forcegid,addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.22,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,mapposix,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
//company.network.com/share_B /home/user/mnt/share_B type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=user,uid=1001,forceuid,gid=1001,forcegid,addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.34,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,mapposix,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

The only difference I see is the IP-address.

#### Question

How can I stop the mount of `share_B` becoming "corrupted"?

#### What I've tried

##### Remounting

I can workaround this issue by unmounting share B and mounting it again:

```
sudo umount /home/user/mnt/share_B
sudo mount /home/user/mnt/share_B
```

##### Checking the log

I have looked in the log with `dmesg -wT`, which shows the following directly after the mount of both shares:

```
[Fri Oct  7 09:32:28 2022] CIFS: Attempting to mount //company.network.com/share_B
[Fri Oct  7 09:32:28 2022] CIFS VFS: \\company.network.com error -2 on ioctl to get interface list
[Fri Oct  7 09:35:21 2022] CIFS: Attempting to mount //company.network.com/share_A
[Fri Oct  7 09:35:21 2022] CIFS VFS: \\company.network.com error -2 on ioctl to get interface list
[Fri Oct  7 09:35:21 2022] FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected
[Fri Oct  7 09:35:21 2022] FS-Cache: O-cookie c=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [p=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX fl=222 nc=0 na=1]
[Fri Oct  7 09:35:21 2022] FS-Cache: O-cookie d=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX n=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[Fri Oct  7 09:35:21 2022] FS-Cache: O-key=[10] 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
[Fri Oct  7 09:35:21 2022] FS-Cache: N-cookie c=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [p=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX fl=2 nc=0 na=1]
[Fri Oct  7 09:35:21 2022] FS-Cache: N-cookie d=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX n=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Despite the errors, both mounts work.
When I scroll back to see if there is anything logged during the night (when `share_B` got disconnected) I only see a stream of (what I think are) Docker related network changes, and nothing about mounts.

```
...
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:30 2022] device veth7c5d17e entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:30 2022] br-8a3b7730e904: port 3(veth7c5d17e) entered blocking state
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:30 2022] br-8a3b7730e904: port 3(veth7c5d17e) entered forwarding state
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] eth0: renamed from veth97841fd
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth7c5d17e: link becomes ready
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] br-8a3b7730e904: port 4(vetheaf796c) entered blocking state
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] br-8a3b7730e904: port 4(vetheaf796c) entered disabled state
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] device vetheaf796c entered promiscuous mode
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] br-8a3b7730e904: port 4(vetheaf796c) entered blocking state
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] br-8a3b7730e904: port 4(vetheaf796c) entered forwarding state
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] br-8a3b7730e904: port 4(vetheaf796c) entered disabled state
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] eth0: renamed from vethe1d01ad
[Fri Oct  7 04:02:31 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetheaf796c: link becomes ready
...
```

##### Periodically polling the mount

In my attempts to find when the corruption occurs, I created below crontab entry to periodically check the `stat` output of the problematic mount.
My idea was that I could then find a timestamp around which I could search the logs.

```
user@host:~$ crontab -l
*/10 *  *  *  * echo "$(date) $(stat --terse /home/user/mnt/share_B)" >> /home/user/temp/share_B_mount_check.log
```

Mysteriously this prevented the issue from happening, so I can now also work around the issue by periodically polling the mounted folder.

I have played around with the polling interval and found that if it is longer than 15 minutes, the mount of `share_B` becomes corrupted.

Comment: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_troubleshooting https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/Documentation-filesystems-cifs-README

Comment: You're using Samba & winbind, sure. But with or without sssd? Is the client machine joined to an AD environment? Are the servers really Windows machines or are they also Samba -based serves?

Comment: I am still figuring out how to check if SSSD is used and what the OS of the servers is (`smbclient -L host` does not return the OS in my case, only the available folders. I'm afraid of using `nmap` as that might be seen as nefarious, raising unnecesary red flags), but based on the output of `sudo realm list` I am not joined to an AD (`No configured realms`).